# How to change(down grade) OpenCV referenced

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

[Ubuntu14.04]

I'm trying to run darknet.
(https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolov2/)

I have the error caused by that I'm using OpenCV 3.4.2 version.

> (terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
> what():
> OpenCV(3.4.2)/home/kasamatsu/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix_wrap.cpp:800:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) (flags & FIXED_TYPE) != 0 in function
> 'type')

I found I can solve the problem by changing the version of OpenCV used.
But I have no ideas about how to change it.

now my
`/etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf`
says `/usr/local/lib`

my `/usr/local/lib`includes

- libopencv_highgui.so.3.2
- libopencv_highgui.so.3.2.0
- libopencv_highgui.so.3.4
- libopencv_highgui.so.3.4.2

  ・・・and so on.
  So I think my environment references only libopencv_highgui.so.3.4.2.
  I would like to change this target.

I am a beginner of stack overflow and OpenCV.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The answer will probably depend on the "make" system you're using, e.g. `cmake`. Can you add the information how you're building your app?

Comment: Thanks to your Hint "make system", I solved the problem by checking settings of make and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf.